# Latin letters are displayed instead of cyrillic

Tags: support

In [that answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/298/109) the word отладчик is incorrectly displayed on my screen.

[image]

Interestingly, in the comments the word is shown correctly (and also in this post).

The wrong letters look like those from the Latin alphabet, but they neither are the Latin equivalent nor do have the same position on a different keyboard layout (as far as I know).

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Wait, what did you expect lowercase а to look like? A scaled-down uppercase А?

Comment: What's wrong with it? Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're just not familiar with Russian cursive.

[image]
<sub>(source: [forumlocal.ru](http://forumlocal.ru/user/upload/file329381.jpg))</sub>

The word written is `дышишь`. Here's how it is rendered in cursive:

> *дышишь*

Comment: Why is that so? Who did invent such a thing?

Comment: @Em1: Bwa-ha-ha! Monks in `XIV` century did. It emerged from grazhdanskoye pis'mo which originated from skopopis' which originated from poluustav.

Comment: Hah, I've been looking for that picture.

Comment: The best/worst word to write in cursive is милиции :D