# Request for true italics

Tags: feature-request, design

##### tl;dr

Please change the site font to the serif stack (Georgia), so that we can have   on the Russian Language site.

---

### Italics

Italics is used to emphasise or draw attention to certain words or passages by using a visual contrast.  Some typefaces use     and some use   .  These are not the same; a slanted font shows much less contrast than true italics.
Compared to a regular font, true italics uses some completely different letter shapes.  In particular, the following lowercase Cyrillic letters (amongst others):

- *г, д, и, л, т, ш*

... should look very different in a true italic font, something more like:

- *ƨ, ∂/g, u, ʌ, m, ɯ*

#### Cursive

The Russian language is usually handwritten in a cursive script. This is also not the same as an italic font, but it is closely related.  By design, most of the italic letter shapes closely resemble their cursive counterparts.  A slanted font makes no attempt to do this.

### Many existing posts don't make sense anymore

A significant number of questions, answers, and comments that were posted when there was a true italic font *were relying on this feature* to make sense.
Examples include these excerpts:

- from [What is the preferred form of Cyrillic to use for handwriting?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/what-is-the-preferred-form-of-cyrillic-to-use-for-handwriting):

  > [image: Question attempting to compare the roman type and italic type of the letters: "г", "д", "и" "й" and "т"]
- from [Do adult Russians normally hand-write Cyrillic as cursive or as block letters?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/19764/do-adult-russians-normally-hand-write-cyrillic-as-cursive-or-as-block-letters):

  > [image: Question attempting to show the quite large difference that italics makes to the letters: "д", "т", and "и"]
- from [What are these Russian characters that aren't in the alphabet in my learning material?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/16675/18988):

  > [image: Answer attempting to show contrast between the regular and italicised forms of: "Тт", "Йй", "Дд", and "Гг"]
- from [Latin letters are displayed instead of Cyrillic](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/121/18988):

  > [image: Meta answer attempting to show the cursive (recte italic) form of the word "дышишь"]
- from [What Russian letter is this?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/13537/18988):

  > [image: Comment attempting to show the significantly different italic shapes of "г" and "т"]
- from [When to use ∂ and when to use the g-type for little д?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/2948/18988):

  > [image: Answer attempting to show the "italic" forms of: "д"]

Without true italics, the above posts (and many others) don't make sense; they have now become obscured, confusing and have lost their usefulness.

### System fonts

A few years ago the Stack Exchange network started using systems fonts.
(See: [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021))
The system fonts (typeface) looks like this:

[image: Sample of the System-UI typeface: regular, oblique, and bold. All the lowercase letters of the standard Russian alphabet, plus 4 pre-reform letters, and accented vowels.]

It's a sans serif typeface with slanted rather than true italics.  It's dull, it's hard to read, and (at least on my setup) it can't even render accented letters correctly.

### Georgia

There are however, several sites that do use to a serif typeface with true italics.  Most of these (such as [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com)) use the typeface "Georgia", which has all the necessary characters for the Russian language (including a few pre-reform letters):

[image: Sample of the Georgia typeface: regular, italics, and bold. All the lowercase letters of the standard Russian alphabet, plus 4 pre-reform letters, and accented vowels.]

EL&U uses this typeface not only because it looks much better, but because it is functionally more appropriate.
(See also: [Can we at least select our fonts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes/307865#307865))

#### A different typeface?

I'm suggesting that we use "Georgia" on the Russian Language site.  This is only because: it has true italics, it apparently works on various setups, and it shouldn't be too hard to implement.  But, any other serif typeface with true italics would suit me just fine.

Perhaps there is a typeface with a particularly Russian feel about it, which would instil a certain sense of pride in the written form of the language that appears on our site.
However, the typeface would have to be compatible with the various supported web browsers and operating systems.  It should and also have glyphs for the pre-reform characters such as: ѣ, і, ѵ, and ѳ.

---

Changing the font would also solve the [stress mark bug](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/508/stress-mark-bug) problem I am having, but that is not my primary concern here.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Elements — this font is a bit clinical. If you want a beautiful sans serif font that preserves the true Russian italics, I'd recommend Fira Sans. It's extremely legible at any size, has gorgeous bold, italics and bold italics and an endless array of glyphs from other languages, symbols, and even a full IPA. We professional editors love it because of its kerning and spacing; most every editor I know puts their projects in Fira before editing it. A little professional tip  We don't care much for Georgia because it tends to be wide and take up a lot of room, and the italics are a little narrow and hard to see sometimes, the bold is boxy, and the bold italics are ugly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd much prefer a font with serifs, but Fira Sans is nice for a sans.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace: I, like you, prefer serifs, but as an editor, after a few hours, serifs can make your head spin. I fell in love with Fira the first time I edited a book in it. Now I use it for everything.